# Setting DAY_OF_WEEK returns unexpected result

Tags: java, calendar

I want to set a given calendar instance's timestamp to the beginning of the week (Monday) and instead it returns a seemingly completely unrelated timestamp - unless I access any of the calendar's fields before doing so. I include a sample below, please also see this runnable example in [Ideone](http://ideone.com/rKUD7z).

Is this expected behavior? What's the logic behind this? And yes, I've heard of Joda Time.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;


class MyTest {

private static Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"), Locale.FRANCE);
private static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Set to any date.
    calendar.set(2013, 10, 3);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

    // Set to another day.
    calendar.set(2014, 0, 15);
    // --- THE WTF STARTS HERE ---
    // Uncommenting the line below returns the correct date in the end.
    // calendar.getTime();

    // Set to monday of current week.
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());

    // Expected outdate is 20140113
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

}

}
```

Comment: Can you set the first day like this: calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(0); calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek()); This will return: 20140111   Edit: Zero is Sunday etc.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the Monday 20140113.

Comment: It seems like `getTime` triggers `computeTime` internally... probably setting two dates in a row messes up the calendar's internal state.

Comment: Funny how it seems to work for any "first day of week" _except_ monday...

Comment: Both `Calendar` and Joda-Time are *passé*, supplanted by *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 5):

Field Manipulation chapter in the docs explains it clearly. It just works weird though.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

> Example: Consider a GregorianCalendar originally set to August 31, 1999. Calling 
>       set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SEPTEMBER) sets the date to September 31, 1999. 
>       This is a temporary internal representation that resolves to October 1, 1999 if 
>       getTime()is then called. However, a call to set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30) before the 
>       call to getTime() sets the date to September 30, 1999, since no recomputation occurs 
>       after set() itself.

**EDIT**

From the Calendar Fields Resolution part of the same doc

```
If there is any conflict in calendar field values, Calendar gives priorities to 
calendar fields that have been set more recently. The following are the default 
combinations of the calendar fields. The most recent combination, as determined 
by the most recently set single field, will be used.

For the date fields:

 YEAR + MONTH + DAY_OF_MONTH
 YEAR + MONTH + WEEK_OF_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
 YEAR + MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
 YEAR + DAY_OF_YEAR
 YEAR + DAY_OF_WEEK + WEEK_OF_YEAR
```

I think the difference between MONTH and DAY_OF_WEEK is this. If you set MONTH at the last statement it matches with YEAR+MONTH+DAY_OF_MONTH and overrides all of them. If you set DAY_OF_WEEK it matches with YEAR+DAY_OF_WEEK+WEEK_OF_YEAR so doesn't override the month value. Or something like that. To be honest, the more I look the more broken it seems. It doesn't make sense at all. Better keep using JodaTime

Comment: calendar.getTime()->getTimeInMillis()->updateTime()->computeTime()

Comment: (+1) I was totally unable to put that in words, linked to your answer in mine. Calling `calendar.clear();`  will reset the value and allow another clear calendar.set(int, int, int) to be used.

Comment: @RossC Yep, it seems either clear() or get() function should be called

Comment: Thanks, interesting - that would explain it. However, if in the last set I set `Calendar.MONTH` like: `calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);` it works even without a prior `calendar.getTime();` In any case - this is horribly unintuitive.

Comment: "Horribly Unintuitive" yeah that about sums it up! :) Glad it is working and cleared up.

Comment: @tobias_k It's funny that the exact example from the Javadoc you quoted does exactly the opposite i.e it returns October 1, 1999 (as a sane person may expect). I tried this on Java 6/7. It seems that "not re-computing time" until one of the getters is called only applies to some fields - such as `Calenbdar.DAY_OF_WEEK`. I wonder if this is by chance or implementation dependant - and thus cannot be relied on - or normal.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clear the calendar as it retains values?

[Kaya's answer about why this would be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631866/setting-day-of-week-returns-unexpected-result/20632156#20632156)

E.g:

```
calendar.clear();
// Set to another day.
calendar.set(2014, 0, 14);
```

This returns:

**20140113** rather than *20131223* as you were previoiusly getting.

From the docs:

> **void java.util.Calendar.set(int year, int month, int date)**
>
> Sets the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, and DAY_OF_MONTH.
>   Previous values of other calendar fields are retained. If this is not
>   desired, call clear() first.

Comment: I could do that - but why would I do that? I override all the necessary fields.

Comment: Edited for 'Monday'. As someone else said above "seems like getTime triggers computeTime internally... probably setting two dates in a row messes up the calendar's internal state." Answered by @kaya in answers. Using clear() will undo the issue as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )                  // Get the current date for a particular region.
    .with(             
        TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )  // Move to an earlier date that is Monday, or stay on same date if it already *is* Monday.
    )                                                         // Return `LocalDate` object.
```

## java.time

The `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes, specifically `ZonedDateTime`.  So the Question is now moot.

Among the problems with the legacy class is that the definition of the start-of-week varies by locale, and crazy numbering schemes for year, month, and day-of-week. In contrast, java.time by default always considers Monday the start of the week, running through Sunday, per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. And java.time using sane numbering:

- `2018` is the year 2018, no messy math with 1900.
- 1-12 for months January-December.
- 1-7 for Monday-Sunday.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## Adjuster

To move from one date to another, use a `TemporalAdjuster` implementation found in `TemporalAdjusters` class. Specify the desired day-of-week using [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-) enum.

```
LocalDate previousOrSameMonday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).