# Calendar set DAY_OF_WEEK not correct

Tags: android, calendar

Hi i have some problem with `DAY_OF_WEEK`. After research but don't know why.

**`Input date is :`**

```
30/01/2016 - SATURDAY
```

**`After run :`**

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
```

**`Output :`**

```
31/01/2016 - SUNDAY(Wrong).
```

I want it must `30/01/2016 - SATURDAY`, 
Please help me ?

Comment: Show how you are setting the data and reading it at the end of the process...

Comment: Similar Question: [Setting DAY_OF_WEEK returns unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20631866/642706)

Answer (score 0):

try by passing Date

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance;
calendar.set(2016, Calendar.JANUARY, 30);
```

or try this too

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
   System.out.print("Start Date : " + c.getTime() + ", ");
   c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
}
```

Comment: But I want DYNAMIC input and will get SATURDAY for this.

Comment: But I want DYNAMIC input? i did not get you.For the above code every **SATURDAY** in month will display.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.JANUARY , 30 )
    .with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) )
```

> 2016-02-06

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes rather than the troublesome old `Calendar` class that is now legacy.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## Adjuster

To move from one date to another, use a `TemporalAdjuster` implementation found in `TemporalAdjusters` class. Specify the desired day-of-week using [`DayOfWeek`][2] enum.

```
LocalDate previousOrSameMonday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).